# Get index path for section header view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two tables on my ViewController. I am adding cell from one table to the other by drag and drop. Now my destination table is a grouped table where I have implemented expand - collapse logic. The section header view is a custom UIView. My problem is that when I drag a cell to destination table section, I want that section to open or expand. But I am unable to get its index path to do so.

How can I get the index path for the destination table's section?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I used gesture recognizer's locationInView: method to get the current point.
I used the parameters like the table frame, row height and section header custom view's height to calculate which section is touched under the dragged cell and hence got the index path for that section.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can implemented the touches began animation and if finger touches the destination  table view get the touch coordinate and calculate for the section in the destination table.
Lil tricky but hope it works for you.